# CSV.table が CSV.read に比べて非常に遅い理由

Tags: ruby, csv

タブ区切りの3,000行ほどのCSVファイルを `CSV.table` で読み込もうとすると非常に遅かったので `CSV.read` を試してみたところ100分の1程度で処理できました。

```
Benchmark.bm 10 do |r|
  r.report "read" do
    CSV.read(filename, col_sep: "\t", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol)
  end
  r.report "table" do
    CSV.table(filename, col_sep: "\t")
  end
end
                 user     system      total        real
read         0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.046571)
table        4.790000   0.010000   4.800000 (  4.814375)
```

`CSV.table`は常に`CSV.read`に対してこれほど速度差があるのでしょうか、
それとも何か特別な原因がある時だけ遅くなるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

table には `converters: :numeric` が含まれています。
数値を変換しようとするので、遅くなります。

```
  def self.table(path, options = Hash.new)
    read( path, { headers:           true,
                  converters:        :numeric,
                  header_converters: :symbol }.merge(options) )
  end
```

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_1/lib/csv.rb#L1354-L1358

`CSV.read` の方に `converters :numeric` を追加すると、実行時間は同じになると思います。

Comment: 確認してみたところ確かに `converters: :numeric` を追加すると遅くなりました。ありがとうございます。